# Using pre-assigned value from R outside of cppFunction

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpp11

I am wondering if there is an easy way to call the pre-assigned values in r when I wrote cppFunction.

Here is my code:

```
y=45.3
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction(
"NumericVector demo_fun_cpp(double x) {
    NumericVector out1(50);
    out1[0] = 2;
    for (int i=1; i < 50; ++i) {
        out1[i]=x+y+out1[i-1];
    }
    return out1;
}" )
```

> Error: in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir,  : Error 1 occurred building shared library.

I understand if I assign `y` inside of `demo_fun_cpp()` function, it will work. However, there are a lot of values that has been assigned in R, so it will be very convenient if I don't have to assign them again.

I am new in C++, I appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: There are other methods (environment variables, say, or accessing R values) but those are _worse_.  Code clarity first.  If you need it, pass it through the function signature.

Comment: I think you could access to the global environment (assuming the variables are there) but the code is as complex as passing all the neeeded variables to the function...

Comment: Great! I appreciate all suggestions! I will try these solutions!